# Chrome extension how to append or edit a csv file on pc

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am able to find some information on how to read a csv file on a computer but is there any way I can modify one? In my chrome extension I need to add data to each row one at a time after scraping some websites. Is there any better way then read csv, store data as variable and rewrite is everytime? This becomes problematic when the file gets large. I am looking for a way to “append ” to a existing file or a work around. Any suggestions appreciated.

Update: From comment I see it is not possible to read from file system. But is there anyway to read from within the extension directory? How should I do so if the csv file is included with in the zip file of the extension? Can I access them somehow? Code snippets would be helpful.

Comment: Extensions can't write to arbitrary local files directly. Chrome extensions have a local file system (deprecated) but it obfuscates file names and the location is buried deep inside browser user profile. Chrome apps can access file system, but only in ChromeOS. The only "solution" is to write an external separate utility that runs in OS, communicates with your extension via [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging), and reads/writes the file(s) accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the middle of creating something which might help you. Right now you can upload the CSV file and append a "modifier". You can adjust the code according to your requirement. Here's the repo https://github.com/amanrOnly/CSV_Modifier

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33735164)

Comment: Thanks @DJSDev I'll add code snippet for the core logic.